# Redirect the users to the page they were watching before logging in or registering an account

Tags: 7, users

I have a custom login, sign-in and sign-up page in two tabs; I want logged-in users to be redirected to the same page they were watching before logging in or creating an account.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want to keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out. If it is so, then download and install the [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module. It is also possible to keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.